# Bash command to search pattern (sequence) and print everything what's next to the pattern (to the right and left side)

Tags: bash, printing, match, sequence

I'm trying to reconstruct a gene sequence based on a PoolSeq file of a population (fasta format) and a conserved area. I  want to search the file for matches with this sequence and then build up the neighboring area starting from that conserved sequence.

So I basically need a Bash command to search a fasta file for a sequence segment and to print the neighboring region of the match in every read.

File:
Fasta file of dieverse Individuals of a species

Input:
20-30 bp Sequence

Output:
All reads with that sequence and the neighboring region in that read

Answer (score 0):

you can try with grep:

`grep -o -E '.{,20}ATGCGT.{,20}' test.fasta`
description:

`-o`  show only the part of the line that match

`-E` use extended regex

REGEX:

- `.{,20}` up to 20 any char before
- ATGCGT seq you want to match
- `.{,20}` up to 20 any char after